# Best way to use special keys like [CTRL]+[UP] with onkeyup in all browsers

Tags: jquery, hotkeys, onkeyup

How can I use jQuery onkeyup to use these (multi) keys in all new browsers?

- <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>DOWN</kbd>
- <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>UP</kbd>
- <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>DOWN</kbd>
- <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>UP</kbd>
- <kbd>DOWN</kbd>
- <kbd>UP</kbd>

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Comment: @Andreas they also should have typos or missing spaces.

Comment: So you're aware, @Peter, on StackOverflow we expect people to use English in all cases. Not txtspk. Imperfect grammar is fine, if not ideal, but please use the most correct English you know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the [Hotkeys plugin for jQuery](http://code.google.com/p/js-hotkeys/)!

**EDIT:** This is a working hotkey plugion version (its pretty short):

```
(function(jQuery){jQuery.hotkeys={version:"0.8",specialKeys:{8:"backspace",9:"tab",13:"return",16:"shift",17:"ctrl",18:"alt",19:"pause",20:"capslock",27:"esc",32:"space",33:"pageup",34:"pagedown",35:"end",36:"home",37:"left",38:"up",39:"right",40:"down",45:"insert",46:"del",96:"0",97:"1",98:"2",99:"3",100:"4",101:"5",102:"6",103:"7",104:"8",105:"9",106:"*",107:"+",109:"-",110:".",111:"/",112:"f1",113:"f2",114:"f3",115:"f4",116:"f5",117:"f6",118:"f7",119:"f8",120:"f9",121:"f10",122:"f11",123:"f12",144:"numlock",145:"scroll",191:"/",224:"meta"},shiftNums:{"`":"~","1":"!","2":"@","3":"#","4":"$","5":"%","6":"^","7":"&","8":"*","9":"(","0":")","-":"_","=":"+",";":": ","'":"\"",",":"<",".":">","/":"?","\\":"|"}};function keyHandler(handleObj){if(typeof handleObj.data!=="string"){return}var origHandler=handleObj.handler,keys=handleObj.data.toLowerCase().split(" ");handleObj.handler=function(event){if(this!==event.target&&(/textarea|select/i.test(event.target.nodeName)||event.target.type==="text")){return}var special=event.type!=="keypress"&&jQuery.hotkeys.specialKeys[event.which],character=String.fromCharCode(event.which).toLowerCase(),key,modif="",possible={};if(event.altKey&&special!=="alt"){modif+="alt+"}if(event.ctrlKey&&special!=="ctrl"){modif+="ctrl+"}if(event.metaKey&&!event.ctrlKey&&special!=="meta"){modif+="meta+"}if(event.shiftKey&&special!=="shift"){modif+="shift+"}if(special){possible[modif+special]=true}else{possible[modif+character]=true;possible[modif+jQuery.hotkeys.shiftNums[character]]=true;if(modif==="shift+"){possible[jQuery.hotkeys.shiftNums[character]]=true}}for(var i=0,l=keys.length;i<l;i++){if(possible[keys[i]]){return origHandler.apply(this,arguments)}}}}jQuery.each(["keydown","keyup","keypress"],function(){jQuery.event.special[this]={add:keyHandler}})})(jQuery);
```

Comment: This plugin is not rly up2date .. right? last update -> May 03, 2009 ... Did it rly works for every new browser?

Comment: as far as i know yes (but i as far as i remember we had to patch it)